# How to undo a git push?

Tags: git

I pushed up some files up to github using `git push <branch_name>`. When I open a PR, the files show up in the changes. How do I undo this `git push`? In short, I tried to do a `git reset` of that file before pushing but apparently I mistyped the filename. Now what do I do?

How do I undo pushes to Github?

Comment: Is this repository contributed to by other developers? Has anyone made any changes ot it since?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, make a backup, in case something goes wrong. Clone your repository as `<repository>-backup` with `-b <branchname>` and don't touch that one.

Second, find the commit hash of the last good commit in `git log`.

Then run:

```
git push --force origin <last good commit hash>:<branch>
```

Note that rewriting history is generally considered a bad idea, unless you're the only user of the repository. If other people have pulled down the repository with a commit change, and you force push and remove that commit, the repository will enter a corrupted state.

Unless you pushed some sensitive information you really need to remove, just revert the commit with:

```
git revert <commit hash to revert>
git push
```

Comment: This just saved my day